# How to fix issue with taking a Screenshot and exporting it to Extent Report in Listener class for testng?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, extentreports

I'm creating a TestNG Maven framework.
I have a problem with taking a screenshot on test failure and uploading it to Extent Report
Below is Extent Report listener.

```java
String targetLocation = null;

String testClassName = result.getInstanceName();
String errorDate = new SimpleDateFormat("(MM.dd.YYYY HH-mm-ss)").format(new Date());
String testMethodName = result.getName();
String screenShotName = testMethodName + errorDate + ".png";
String fileSeperator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
String reportsPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + fileSeperator + "TestReport" + fileSeperator

File src = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

targetLocation = reportsPath + fileSeperator + testClassName + fileSeperator + screenShotName;
try {
    File targetFile = new File(targetLocation);

    FileHandler.copy(src, targetFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.info("File not found exception occurred while taking screenshot " + e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.info("An exception occurred while taking screenshot " + e.getCause());
}

// attach screenshots to report
try {
    ExtentTestManager.getTest().fail("Screenshot", MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(targetLocation).build());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.info("An exception occured while taking screenshot " + e.getCause());
}
ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(Status.FAIL, "Test Failed");
```

Comment: What exactly the issue you are facing here? Exceptions? stacktrace?

Comment: I don't get any code errors, but the screenshot is not taken. The output file is null. I've tried to use FileUtils instead of FileHandler when copying file, but still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Simply put this code for screenshot.

```
ExtentTestManager.startTest(method.getName(), description);
ExtentTest extentTest = ExtentTestManager.getTest();
String base64Screenshot = "data:image/png;base64," + ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
extentTest.log(LogStatus.FAIL, logs, ExtentTestManager.getTest().addBase64ScreenShot(base64Screenshot));
```